# CG change/saving context when drawing a subpath

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics

If I am doing a simple drawing, and I want to change the line width/dash of certain sub paths, how can I achieve this without changing all the paths?  I have tried a few variations using CGContextSaveGState(context); but can't quite get it right.  Do this have to be totally different paths?  I really want them to not look painted over with shadows.

```
- (void)drawPitch:(CGContextRef)context {

    // Push the context onto the stack
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);

    //Reasonable defaults
    CGRect          pitchRect = CGRectMake(10, 10, 220, 344);
    CGSize          myShadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,1);
    float           myColorValues[] = {0, 0, 0, 0.75};
    CGColorRef      myColor;
    CGColorSpaceRef myColorSpace;

    //Color Space
    myColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB ();
    myColor = CGColorCreate (myColorSpace, myColorValues);

    // Set Stroke
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1, 1, 1, 0.9);

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 4);

    // Pitch Outline at width:4
    CGContextAddRect(context, pitchRect);

    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    // Want this to be set width:2 just for the subpath
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, CGRectGetMinX(pitchRect), CGRectGetMinY(pitchRect) + (pitchRect.size.height * 0.50));
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, CGRectGetMaxX(pitchRect), CGRectGetMinY(pitchRect) + (pitchRect.size.height * 0.50));

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);


    // Set Line Shadow
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, myShadowOffset, 10, myColor);


    // Stroke path
    CGContextStrokePath(context);


    // Pop the contect back on the stack
    UIGraphicsPopContext();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to `CGContextSetLineWidth()` only affects the call to `CGContextStrokePath()`. A path only contains the coordinates and types of each segment, and does not contain information about line width or pattern or anything else. If you need to draw each segment with a different line width, then you need to use separate calls to `CGContextStrokePath()` with separate paths.